# Why does it put "or" instead of "," in this example? Difference in meaning?

Tags: sentence-meaning, difference, commas

Why does it put "or" instead of "," in the following example? 
https://7esl.com/verbs/

1)"or" sentence: Noun refers to the words or pharses that represent a person, a place, a thing or activity, or a quality or idea.

2)"," sentence: Noun refers to the words or phrases that represent a person, a place, a thing, an activity, a quality and an idea.

What's the difference in meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People and places are proper nouns. Things and activities are common nouns. Qualities and ideas are abstract nouns. The writer of the definition has chosen to link *things or activities* and *qualities or ideas* together in the list.

Your version would work if you changed the ending to *or an idea.*